# Loop search a column, if a value is found in a cell in that column, then add that value to the value already in an adjacent cell on the same row

Tags: excel, vba

Example

```
      A    B    C    D
1
2     15        16
3
```

VBA loop macro found value in cell C2 so it add this value to the value in the same row Cell A2  thus making the value of Cell A2 31 and clears the value from Cell C2

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim y, x, search as Integer
Dim searchRadius as Integer    'Radius of Cells you want to search in (e.g. 100x100)

search = TextBox1.Value        'set search to something 
y = 1
x = 2

For y = 1 To searchRadius
    If Cells(y, x) = search Then
        Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(y, 1).Value + search
        Cells(y, x).Select
        Cells(y, x) = ""
    End If
    If y = searchRadius and x <= searchRadius Then
        x = x + 1 
        y = 0
    End If
Next y
```

Does this work for you?